# What is the meaning of the difference between the equations of two non-intersecting circles represent?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, circles

The difference between the equations of two intersecting circles gives a linear equation which represents the common chord or the common tangent.

But what about two non-intersecting circles?

I experimented with a number of different circles of varying centre and radius but I can't find an answer. The resulting line is perpendicular to the line joining the centres but its position doesn't make much sense to me.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's their radical axis: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_axis

Comment: Interesting, that answers my question, thanks.

Comment: If you allow complex solutions to the system of equations, they also satisfy the equation of the line. In a sense, then, this line always passes through the intersections of the circles.

Comment: @amd I don't know what that means. Could you show an example ?

Comment: The equations $x^2+y^2=2$ and $(x-3)^2+y^2=2$ are satisfied by $x=3/2$, $y=\pm i/2$, which also satisfies the difference $6x-9=0$ of the equations. One can consider these two imaginary points to be the intersections of the circles, which nevertheless lie on a real line. This point of view is useful in projective geometry, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Difference of two non intersecting circles is a line perpendicular to the line joining the centre of the two circles.

The line always lies between the two circles(near to the smaller one) and touches neither of them(for non intersecting circles).

The distance of the line from mid-point of centres is equal to "difference of squares of radii, divided by twice the distance between centres". It can be written as :
$$
d=\frac{|a^2-b^2|}{2L}
$$
where

- $d$ the distance of line from mid of centres
- $a$ and $b$ are radii
- $L$ distance between centre of circles